# deleting java from system library on mac

Tags: mac, java, macos

I can't delete java from my mac. I tried deleting it from system/Library, but it says the os mac system needs it. I want to install an older version because a specific website needs it, but it keeps using the newer version that i can't uninstall.

Comment: What version do you need? The one in /System will be java 6 at most.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this useful article:](http://osxdaily.com/2017/06/16/uninstall-java-mac/)

> Quit out of any active web browser or  any other app which uses Java
>
> From the Mac Finder, pull down the “Go”  menu and choose “Go To
>   Folder” and  enter the following path:
>
> ```
> /Library/Interned Plug-ins/
> ```
>
> Locate and delete “`JavaAppletPlugin.plugin`” from this  folder – note
>   moving this item to the trash requires an admin login
>
> [image]
>
> Now go back to the ‘Go’ menu and “Go To Folder” and enter the
>   following path:
>
> ```
> /Library/PreferencePanes/
> ```
>
> Locate and delete  “`JavaControlPanel.prefPane`” from this  folder,
>   again you will need an admin  login
>
> Again return to the “Go” menu and “Go  to Folder” to the following
>   path:
>
> ```
> ~/Library/Application Support /Java/
> ```
>
> Remove the “Java” folder
>
> Empty the Trash on the Mac as usual

Comment: Java apps do not use the internet plugin

Comment: @Mark That's just a weird way the java packages are installed under MacOS (even today, the installers from Oracle do that, too). The `java` executable is actually inside that *plugin package*, which just has the "Applet" part in its name. Unless java was also installed elsewhere (e.g. using brew or such) that's where it lives.

Comment: @Gero no Oracles ones are in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines

Comment: @Mark That only goes for the JDK. Admittedly, Java 11 doesn't provide a stand-alone JRE install anymore, but the versions before that did. You didn't even check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/install/installed-directory-structure-jdk-and-jre.htm#JSJIG-GUID-F7178F2F-DC92-47E9-8062-CA6B2612D350) it seems. Anyways, the statement "Java apps do not use the internet plugin" is misleading, as said .plugin package does indeed contain the java VM and unless you install the JDK or otherwise mess with it (as I noted), that's used.

Comment: @Bence and D Manokhim: To get back on track, that guide should work (so upvote), at least as long as it's not an ancient installation (I can't remember where it was before Java 6). Even if you used the JDK (be it for Java 11 or otherwise), the procedure is more or less the same, just adapt the paths (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/) under "installation guide" for where it was installed to, ensuring you jumped to the correct Java version before that).